# How do I get a specific item from my ListBox to show in a txt box

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm currently making a program that lets the user select an ID number and the one that the user picks from a list box will show the first name, last name, and hobby in three separate txt boxes. The data you get from the ID, names, and hobbies are all read from a csv file. How exactly do I select one ID to show the data I want in the txt boxes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StudentInformation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        List<ID> events = new List<ID>();
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("class.csv");
            {
                foreach(var line in lines)
                {
                    String[] words = line.Split(',');
                    string Id = words[0];
                    string last = words[1];
                    string first = words[2];
                    string hobby = words[3];
                    listBox1.Items.Add(last);
                    double.Parse(listBox1.SelectedItems) == 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace StudentInformation
{
    class ID
    {
        string Id;
        string FirstName;
        string LastName;
        string Hobby;
        public ID(string eId,string eFirstName, string eLastName, string eHobby)
        {
            Id = eId;
            FirstName = eFirstName;
            LastName = eLastName;
            Hobby = eHobby;
        }
        public override string ToString() => $"{Id}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a dictionary in the back end - the item you select from your dropdown would be the key for your Dictionary<string,ID> (which you would set up when you parse your csv)

then inside your listbox index changed code you could do something like

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(listbox1.Text))
   {
           //clear textboxes here
    }
  else
  {
       var student = studentDictionary[listbox1.Text];
       //populate textboxes here
   }
```

Some slight generic coding tips though, work on your class and object naming conventions. Never name a class 'ID' - even if your class represents an ID, be more specific as ID gets used as a property everywhere. Depending on how much you care about this project, you might also want to do some checks when loading the csv into the dictionary to make sure you don't have duplicate students, students with blank values or blank csv lines being loaded in. You should probably also make ID a public class, and make it's fields public as well.

edit:

You may also want to consider switching to a combobox with dropdownstyle dropDownList - it seems like it might be more applicable to your situation

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `List<ID>`, and query the corresponding item via LINQ.

Besides, you need to define the corresponding properties in class `ID`.

```
class ID
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Hobby { get; set; }

    public ID(string eId, string eFirstName, string eLastName, string eHobby)
    {
        Id = eId;
        FirstName = eFirstName;
        LastName = eLastName;
        Hobby = eHobby;
    }
}
```

Here is a simple demo using LINQ.

```
// list to store all items
List<ID> iDs = new List<ID>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get data from csv
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("class.csv");
    {
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            String[] words = line.Split(',');
            string Id = words[0];
            string last = words[1];
            string first = words[2];
            string hobby = words[3];
            // add items to list
            iDs.Add(new ID(Id, last, first, hobby));
            // add ids to listbox
            listBox1.Items.Add(Id);
        }
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // LINQ query
    ID id = iDs.Where(x => x.Id == listBox1.Text).FirstOrDefault();
    tblast.Text = id.LastName;
    tbfirst.Text = id.FirstName;
    tbhobby.Text = id.Hobby;
}
```